# MySQL can't write to tmp folder, how do I find this tmp folder

Tags: mysql, filesystems, find, mamp

MySQL (using MAMP) says it can't write to `Can't create/write to file '/private/var/folders/AO/AOyal7b0GU844L1VJDb3Bk+++TI/-Tmp-/#sqld035_6_0.MYI`

But using finder I can't find this location. How can I find this location so I can clear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql> show variables like 'tmpdir';
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                              |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| tmpdir        | /var/folders/v+/v+g2dk4fH8qEA4rg+GeRNk+++TI/-Tmp-/ |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```